# Showing popup menu to menu item

Tags: java, swing

My problem is this

I want to show a popup menu to a menu item in java, this i can easily achieve,

but when i am showing the popup menu the parent menu clears,

behaviour i want is parent menu also should be visible while showing popup menu

Comment: how 'bout showing us what you are doing?

Comment: problem is that i cannot copy that code....

Comment: a popup menu to a popup menu :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at two demos, [`PopupMenuDemo`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) and [`GraphPanel`](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel), and I don't see any clearing. [`PopupMenuDemo`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) shows a hierarchical submenu, while [`GraphPanel`](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) shows a hierarchical context menu. Do you have an example in which "the parent menu clears."

Addendum: Here's what I see for [`PopupMenuDemo`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup). Neither demo appears to invoke `setVisible()` on the menu.

[image]

Comment: here the popup menu i am showing is JPopupMenu, that means showing popupmenu to a menuitem, but in the popup menu setvisble method it will clear all the other menus...

Answer (score 0):

May I first ask "why"? It seems like very uncommon, thus bad usability. There's a good reason why you don't see this in any main stream application. If you want submenu, use submenu like trashgod's sample.

You can add a `PopupMenuListener` to your parent menu's popup menu, break at `popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible` and see the call stack. In JDK6, It comes from `BasicMenuItemUI#doClick` calling `MenuSelectionManager#clearSelectedPath`.

So if you really have a good reason to surprise user, supply your own menu item UI.